# Laravel eloquent complex queries on relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Desired output:

```
Post
   uid
   comments
          uid
          author
             username
          likes
             uid
                username
   likes
          uid
          user
             username
   author
          uid
          user
             username
```

So currently I have all the comments, likes and author of the post.
But all of them only contains the UID.

**HERE**: Now I wanted to add the username info on the comments, likes and author so I can get the USERNAME or FIRST_NAME of the user who liked the post and other elements.

To break it down.

- Each post contains post details, comments, likes, and the author
- Currently inside the comments is the authors user data (correct)
- Currently the userdata inside the comment contains avatar_id (wrong, I want the avatar link)
- Currently inside the likes is the user_id (wrong, I want the user_data)
- Currently inside the author is the user data but only an ID to the avatar (wrong, I want the link to the avatar from the user_avatars table

My post model.

```
/**
 * Author of a post.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'uid', 'uid');
}   

/**
 * Comments of a post.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post', 'reply_to', 'pid')->with('author');
}

/**
 * Likes of a post.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like', 'pid', 'pid');
}
```

My Controller

```
$post = Post::with('comments', 'likes', 'author')->where('jid', 2)->get();

return $post;
```

---

So technically the Author() should also join to the user_avatars and files because the user_avatars contains File_ID and USER_ID and the files table contains the File_ID and the link to the avatar. **how to do this?**

---

On another note: 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::author()'
If I do this:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like', 'pid', 'pid')->with('author');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem you are facing, I resolved it this way:

**In you post model:**

```
public function user()
{

    return $this->hasOne('User', 'uid', 'uid');

}
```

**Then in your post controller:**

```
$post = Post::where('id', $id)->with('user')->first();
```

**Then in your post blade view:**

```
$post->user->firstname;
```

Of course you can also add the comments and likes to your Eloquent statement.

Let me know if this resolved your problem or not. I can edit the answer into a better solution.